# AWS DMS Source endpoint

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

When I enter Source database connection details
It's giving error as below: (Same connection details are working for by MS SQL Management Studio).

Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=122506, errMessage=Failed to connect [122506] Network error has occurred, errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 08S01 NativeError: 0 Message: [unixODBC][Simba]Connection broken [122502] ODBC general error.]

Any idea on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error is occuring maybe because your sql server running on an ec2 machine doesn't have 1433 port running on it. Although you would see it running in the settings(but is still disabled).

In the cmd type---- netstat -abn 
If it isn't showing 1433 port in the list. It is still disabled.

To enable it..
Restart the sqlserver services from the "services". Hope it would solve your problem.
If it still occurs :
Open sql server manager, enable(if it is disabled) the sql server services and restart the sql server again.